# HTML / JS : How to trace the event handlers and corresponding files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

I need to trace every event-handlers associated to every events of a HTML DOM element for example `Button` in browser like `Chrome` or `Firefox`. I also want to know which file contains the `event-handler function`.

I work in `Rails` framework and `jQuery`. I have so many `JS` file to manage. Its very troublesome to find the `culprit` when some thing in client side goes wrong.

Can some one help me in this regard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Chrome Dev Tool to look up event listeners added to any element, which looks like below.

[image: Event listener tab of Chrome Dev Tool]

1. Right-click the element you'd like to inspect (e.g. some button)
2. Choose 'Inspect Element' in the context menu
3. Select 'Event Listeners' Tab (shown as 1 in the screenshot)
4. To filter listeners only bound to the selected element, set filter to 'Selected Node Only' (shown as 2 in the screenshot)
5. Click the link represented in the right column of the list to get to the listener source code. (shown as 3 in the screenshot)

See also: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles#viewing-element-event-listeners

Comment: but it always points to the `jquery.js` it never points to your actual file right?

Comment: if jquery.js is used, there's no straight way to get to the actual file. Instead you may have to use an uncompressed version of `jquery.js`, set a breakpoint at the line, trigger the event you'd like to debug (and the debugger will pause the execution at the breakpoint), and then look up the **Call Stack**.